# Email template content issue

Tags: magento2, email-templates

This is my code of email

```
$this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
$transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($template)
                 ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                 ->setTemplateVars($temp_vars)
                 ->setFrom($from)
                 ->addTo($supplier_email)
                 ->getTransport();
$bodyMessage = $transport->getMessage()->getBody()->getPartContent(0);
print_r($bodyMessage);
exit;
```

and output of the code

> =0A=0A=0A=0A=0A=0A=0Aa:visited{color:#1979c3;text-decoration:none}a:hov=
>   er{color:#006bb4;text-decoration:underline}a:active{color:#ff5501;text-d=
>   ecoration:underline}=0A=0A=0A= =0A=0A=0A=0A=0A
>   =0A =0A=0A=0A <= /tr>=0A=0A=0A =20= =0A=0A=0A =0A=
>   =0A =0A =0A
>   =0A =0A =0A=0A
>   =0A =0A=0A=0A =20= =0A=0A=0A <= /tr>=0A=0A=0A = =0A=0A=0A =0A=0A=0A =0A
>   =0A =20= Thank you=0A =20=
>
> =0A = =0A =0A =0A

after upgrade

Comment: can you please show your $temp_vars.

Comment: temp var is ok issue is come when is use htm tags like table

Comment: this is my order.html file

Comment: tr>
                        <td>
                            <h2 style="font-size:18px; font-weight:normal; margin:0;">{{var order_type}} #{{var order.increment_id}}</h2>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>